# Thumbs images upload error in codeigniter

Tags: php, image, codeigniter

```
    <?php
    $image = array(
        'name'  =>  'userfile',
        'id'    =>  'userfile',
        );

    $submit = array(
        'name'  => 'submit',
        'id'    => 'submit',
        'value' => 'Upload'
        );
?>
<?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/upload_image', 'id=upload_file'); ?> <!-- must autoload form helper for this -->
<?php echo form_upload($image); ?>
<?php echo form_submit($submit); ?>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

this is main.php in view folder

```
<?php
class Upload_model extends CI_Model{
    var $original_path;
    var $resized_path;
    var $thumbs_path;

    //initialize the path where you want to save your images
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        //return the full path of the directory
        //make sure these directories have read and write permessions
        $this->original_path = realpath(APPPATH.'../uploads/original');
        $this->resized_path = realpath(APPPATH.'../uploads/resized');
        $this->thumbs_path = realpath(APPPATH.'../uploads/thumbs');
    } 

    function do_upload(){
        $this->load->library('image_lib');
        $config = array(
        'allowed_types'     => 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png', //only accept these file types
        'max_size'          => 2048, //2MB max
        'upload_path'       => $this->original_path //upload directory
    );

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $image_data = $this->upload->data(); //upload the image
        print_r($image_data);
        if($image_data){
            echo "uploaded";
        }else {echo "not upload";}

        //your desired config for the resize() function
        $config = array(
        'source_image'      => $image_data['full_path'], //path to the uploaded image
        'new_image'         => $this->resized_path, //path to
        'maintain_ratio'    => true,
        'width'             => 128,
        'height'            => 128
        );

        //this is the magic line that enables you generate multiple thumbnails
        //you have to call the initialize() function each time you call the resize()
        //otherwise it will not work and only generate one thumbnail
        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
        $this->image_lib->resize();

        $config = array(
        'source_image'      => $image_data['full_path'],
        'new_image'         => $this->thumbs_path,
        'maintain_ratio'    => true,
        'width'             => 36,
        'height'            => 36
        );
        //here is the second thumbnail, notice the call for the initialize() function again
        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
        $this->image_lib->resize();

    }
}
```

this is my model 
and controller only load main.php that allow me select image click submit and then controller call model above to load image

the problem is --> there are no error generate but image and thumbs not uploaded to directory why please?

Comment: Which echo occurs `uploaded` or `not uploaded`?

Comment: You're not calling ->do_upload method, so the data should be empty.

Comment: <?php
    class Upload extends CI_Controller{
     public function index(){
      $this->load->view('main');
     }
        public function upload_image(){
      $this->load->model('upload_model');
            $this->upload_model->do_upload();
        }
 // TODO 
    }
    ?> this is controller call do_upload()

Comment: thanks all code run correct,and make thumbs with different size include this line $this->upload->do_upload(); before this line  $image_data = $this->upload->data(); //upload the image